# After changing my GitHub account, I can't change the old account and can't push to the new account

Tags: git, github

`git push -u origin main` 
The following error message will appear when you run the command

```
remote: Permission to [newAccount]/Repo.git denied to [oldAccount].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/[newAccount]/Repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I confirmed the following
The `git config` is set to the new account.
The key of the old account has been deleted in the keychain.
I removed the cache with the command `git credential-cache exit` .
I have checked that it is linked to the correct remote repository with the command `git remote -v`.

I have tried everything I can find on the net, but I have not been able to completely migrate from my old account to my new account and I cannot `git push`.
How can I completely migrate to the new account and `git push`?

Also, the contents of `.gitconfig` are as follows

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
init.defaultbranch=main
user.name=newAccount_name
user.email=newAccount_email
remote.origin.proxy=
remote.origin.proxy=
credential.helper=store
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.required=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
```

Answer (score 1):

### Prerequisites

This assumes you have already gone through the necessary steps to setup direct access from your local machine.

Note that the use of SSH to authenticate is preferred
https://github.com/settings/keys

In this answer, I assume you already have set that up correctly but bounced to the same problem as I did.

In case you have not gone through SSH authentication, you can start from here
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

### Cause

The problem you have is likely that your running ssh-agent still has your old identity stored.

### Steps to fix

To list any identities in your ssh-agent and remove it, do the following:

Open your Terminal

```
ssh-add -l
```

It will list something like this:

```
256 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX <OLD.IDENTITY.EMAIL> (ED25519)
```

If that was your old identity, you can clean it up with:

```
ssh-add -D
```

Terminal should say: `All identities removed.`

Now list again to verify:

```
ssh-add -l
>The agent has no identities.
```

And add the correct identity. If you follow the default steps for SSH configuration on Github you can use the following:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Finally, try to push again:

```
git push -u origin main
```

### Other potential issues

Note that there may be other issues related to this problem.

#### local git user/email

You may have a local git user that is different from your global one.

```
git config --global user.name "YourName"
git config --global user.email "your.email@xyz.com"
```

#### you have configured SSH but are using the https link for your repository and/or remote url

SSH way:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:YourName/yourRepo.git
```

HTTP way:

```
http:/<YOUR_TOKEN>@github.com/YourName/yourRepo
```

to add a token: goto: https://github.com/settings/tokens
Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Token > Tokens (classic)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I'll use it as a reference.

Comment: Hi, @sub how did you make it work?